# Ember table render performance

Tags: ember.js

I am on ember 1.9.1 and trying to render 160ish items and its taking about 3 seconds. I've removed the bindings for most columns using the `unbound` option. My template looks like the following:

```
<table>
  {{#each item in model}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.isFlagged}}</td>
      <td>{{item.status}}</td>
      <td>{{unbound item.title}}</td>
      <td>{{unbound item.list}}</td>
      <td>{{unbound item.scope}}</td>
      <td>{{unbound item.org}}</td>
      <td>{{unbound item.approver}}</td>
      <td>{{item.time}}</td>
      <td>{{unbound item.submitted}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

Each item is a DS.Model with a fair amount of relationships, but even when all data is resolved and I switch between views of data already loaded it continues to take about 3 seconds in Chrome.

I've tried using the Chrome 'Timeline' tool, but I don't know what I am doing. It shows my click (to switch views) then there is a large number of 'Parse HTML' rows  and 11 GC events impacting ~8 MB each GC. So I am surely doing something wrong but I don't know what.

What are the next steps for troubleshooting and tracking down my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately went with [ember-cloaking](https://github.com/eviltrout/ember-cloaking) and moved from a `table` to a list of `div`s (because ember-cloaking didn't support tables). There is a [fork of ember-cloaking](https://github.com/runspired/ember-cloaking/)  that does claim to support tables but that was not available at the time I posted this.

This was also cross posted on the ember discussion forums that lead me to using the library mentioned above - http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/slow-rendering-of-150-item-table/7174